# DataFrame to DataFrameRow conversion (Julia)

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, julia, pingouin

I'm using `Pingouin.jl` to test normality.

In their [docs](https://clementpoiret.github.io/Pingouin.jl/distributions/), we have

```
dataset = Pingouin.read_dataset("mediation")
Pingouin.normality(dataset, method="jarque_bera")
```

Which should return a `DataFrame` with normality `true` or `false` for each `name` in the dataset.

Currently, this broadcasting is deprecated, and I'm unable to concatenate the result in one DataFrame for each unique-column-output (which is working and outputs a DataFrame).

So, what I have so far.

```
function var_norm(df)
  norm = DataFrame([])
  for i in 1:1:length(names(df))
        push!(norm, Pingouin.normality(df[!,names(df)[i]], method="jarque_bera"))
  end
  return norm
end
```

The error I get:

```
julia> push!(norm, Pingouin.normality(df[!,names(df)[1]], method="jarque_bera"))
```

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: `push!` does not allow passing collections of type DataFrame to be pushed into a DataFrame. Only `Tuple`, `AbstractArray`, `AbstractDict`, `DataFrameRow` and `NamedTuple` are allowed.
Stacktrace:
 [1] push!(df::DataFrame, row::DataFrame; promote::Bool)
   @ DataFrames ~/.julia/packages/DataFrames/vuMM8/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:1603
 [2] push!(df::DataFrame, row::DataFrame)
   @ DataFrames ~/.julia/packages/DataFrames/vuMM8/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:1601
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[163]:1
```

*EDIT*: `push!` function was not properly written at my first version of the post. But, the error persists after the change. How can I reformat the output of type `DataFrame` from Pingouin into `DataFrameRow`?

Comment: I haven't used `Pingouin` before, but you might have the arguments for `push!` around the wrong way, as I see you are trying to assign it to `norm`.  If you write `push!(norm, ...)` it will modify `norm` in-place.

Comment: I changed it; but, the issue remais the same. Basically, transform `DataFrame` type into `DataFrameRow`.

Comment: Could you try pushing `only(Pingouin.normality(…))`?  If `Pengouin.normality` returns a dataframe with exactly one row, `only` should return that row, and thus allow you to push into the `DataFrame`.

Comment: If it doesn’t return one row, you’d want push `eachrow` of what `Pengouin.normality` returns (in another `for` loop, or using `foreach`)

Comment: Please make a comment, so I can accept your answer. It's correct. I just tested it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Pengouin.normality` returns a `DataFrame`, you will have to iterate over its results and push one-by-one:

```
df = Pengouin.normality(…)
for row in eachrow(df)
    push!(norms, row)
end
```

If you are sure `Pengouin.normality` returns a `DataFrame` with exactly one row, you can simply write

```
push!(norms, only(Pengouin.normality(…)))
```